# EasyGUI- Integerbox Output

Tags: python, easygui

I just started learning Python, and after messing around and creating a program I wanted to use, I wanted to create a GUI for it. I had no idea how to start with it, so I just looked it up and found [`EasyGUI`](http://easygui.sourceforge.net).

I have it working and everything, but how do I record the answer into a variable?

```
import easygui as eg
n=0
eg.integerbox(msg="What is the max integer in the Sequence, n?"
              , title="blah blah blah"
              , default=0
              , lowerbound=0)
```

I want to set the answer to the question, `What is the max integer in the Sequence, n?` as a variable (for this instance, `n`).

Like `n=output` or something, but there is no 'output' syntax.

Any ideas on how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert on easygui, but I'll give it a stab.

Have you tried something like:

```
import easygui as eg
uservalue = eg.integerbox(msg="What is the max integer in the sequence, n?"
                  , title = "blah blah blah"
                  , default = 0
                  , lowerbound = 0
```

The easygui documentation gives a similar example for choicebox:

```
msg ="What is your favorite flavor?"
title = "Ice Cream Survey"
choices = ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Rocky Road"]
choice = choicebox(msg, title, choices)
```

Comment: This worked; I can use the output from the question for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a variable to the beginning.

So:

```
import easygui as eg
n=0
eg.integerbox(msg="What is the max integer in the Sequence, n?"
          , title="blah blah blah"
          , default=0
          , lowerbound=0)
```

Becomes:

```
import easygui as eg
n=0
variable = eg.integerbox(msg="What is the max integer in the Sequence, n?"
          , title="blah blah blah"
          , default=0
          , lowerbound=0)
```

Then you can use the variable in the normal way. Examples:

```
print(variable)
eg.msgbox(variable)
```